# Wanting the value of an index of a selected item in a listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

How do I retrieve the value of apple?

http://oi59.tinypic.com/2mwbe61.jpg

I know the first line of code isn't correct but it's what I want my remove button to do:

```
private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //string productName = lbxProducts.SelectedItem.Index[0].GetValue;
   //product.RemoveProduct(productName);
   //RenderBasket();
}
```

The first value of an item in my list box is the product name (which is why I want the first element).

My RemoveProduct method:

```
    public void RemoveProduct(string productToRemove, int quantity)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (OrderItem order in OrderItems)
            {
                if (order.ProductName == productToRemove)
                {
                    order.RemoveItems(quantity);
                    if (order.Quantity == 0) { OrderItems.Remove(order); }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is how my listbox (lbxProducts) is populated:

```
private void RenderBasket()
    {

        lbxProducts.Items.Clear();
        txtNumberOfProducts.Text = string.Format("{0}", product.NumberOfProducts);
        txtNumberOfItems.Text = string.Format("{0}", product.NumberOfItems);
        txtTotal.Text = string.Format("{0:C2}", product.BasketTotal);
        Controls.Add(lbxProducts);
        lbxProducts.BeginUpdate();
        foreach (OrderItem item in product.OrderItems)
        {
            lbxProducts.Items.Add(string.Format("{0,-15} \t {1,4} \t {2,10:C2} \t {3,10:C2}",
                item.ProductName, item.Quantity, item.LatestPrice, item.TotalOrder));
        }
        lbxProducts.EndUpdate();
    }
```

I'm new to programming so I'm still not sure of what I can and can't do but I've been at this little stage for too long. Would really appreciate some help here.

Comment: post the definition of lbxProducts and are you trying to get the int value of the index or something else?

Comment: How is `lbxProducts` listbox populated? Post the code. Probably you just need a type cast.

Comment: What do you mean by definition?

Comment: I'm trying to get the value of my first element of my listbox, so I want to know what exactly is the first element of the item that I selected. For example, if the first element is "apple" of my selected item, I want to know that it's apple, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is get the name of the Listbox index then you could do this,

```
listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

and this if you want to get the index of the item in the list

```
//note that the index is 0 based
listBox1.SelectedIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string value = listbox.Items[listbox.SelectedIndex].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
lbxProducts.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

or

```
lbxProducts.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

to get the value of the selected item.

If you have multiple selected items, you can use

```
if (lbxProducts.SelectedIndex != -1)
    lbxProducts.SelectedItems[lbxProducts.SelectedIndex].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
for (int n = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
{
    string removelistitem = "WHATEVER YOU WANT TO REMOVE";
    if (listBox1.Items[n].ToString().Contains(removelistitem))
    {
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(n);
    }
}
```